# MKMapView Trouble

Tags: iphone, ios, google-maps, mkmapview

I am having trouble when trying to use a MKMapView. This is my first time trying to use one of these and I haven't been able to figure out how to work it. Here are the two different pieces of sample code that I used to try to get it to work and neither work:

```
mapView = [[MKMapView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake( 0, 0, 320, 150 )];
MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance( CLLocationCoordinate2DMake( latitude, longitude ), metersPerMile*0.5, metersPerMile*0.5 );
MKCoordinateRegion adjustedRegion = [mapView regionThatFits:region];
[mapView setRegion:adjustedRegion];
```

or

```
mapView = [[MKMapView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake( 0, 0, 320, 150 )];
MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance( CLLocationCoordinate2DMake( latitude, longitude ), metersPerMile*0.5, metersPerMile*0.5 );
[mapView setRegion:region];
```

or

```
mapView = [[MKMapView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake( 0, 0, 320, 150 )];
[self.mapView setRegion:MKCoordinateRegionMake(CLLocationCoordinate2DMake( latitude, longitude ), MKCoordinateSpanMake( 0.01, 0.01 ))];
```

all of these snippets of code do absolutely nothing for the MKMapView. Whenever the view ends up loading, it doesn't do anything and I'm just left looking at all of North America, which isn't very helpful.

If anyone can help me out with this, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Just check you are referring to the actual mapview that is displayed in your screen. You might be setting the region to some other mapview.

Comment: I did check that and double checked that. That is the reason that I call the initWithFrame: method so that I am sure that the mapView I am seeing is the one I am interacting with.

Comment: I agree with ElanthiraiyanS. You're creating a new mkmapview in each of the examples above, but don't show any code adding it to your view. Instead of creating one, why not use the existing one that you put in your xib and hooked up via an outlet (assuming you have used the xib to set up your interface)?

Comment: I had the mapView linked up to a IBOutlet in Interface Builder but decided to break that link and do it myself. When doing this I forgot to add it to self.view. I did this and the map view works. Thanks so much for the help!

Answer (score 1):

You haven't added map to your view.. like `[self.view addSubView:mapView];`

Answer (score 0):

I show the user where he is by implementing – mapView:viewForAnnotation: from MKMapViewDelegate. Take a look at this:

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation
{   
    // If it's the user location, return nil.
    if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]])
    {
            MKCoordinateSpan coordinateSpan = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.009, 0.009);
            [mapView setRegion:MKCoordinateRegionMake(annotation.coordinate, coordinateSpan) animated:YES];
    }
    return nil;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

If you are tying to load the MapView this will help

```
 - (void)mapViewWillStartLoadingMap:(MKMapView *)mapView
  {
     [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES;
     NSLog(@"map loading...");
  }
```